# Hotelling's T (or something similar) on results of relative importance analysis

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, importance

I am using the R package [relaimpo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html) (Grömping, 2006) to analyze the relative importance of 16 regressors on one dependent variable (N=7000). The results show that regressors vary drastically from each other in explained variance, varying between 18.2% and 0.8%. That is, after controlling for each regressor some regressors explain a lot of variance, others only very little.

For the paper, I need to report one overall p value, e.g.: "Overall, regressors varied significantly from each other (p<.001)."

The package only provides me with information about significant differences between regressors A and B, regressors A and C, et cetera, not an overall test.

Since I only have aggregate data here for 16 regressors (18.2%, 16.5%, ..., 0.8%), I don't know what test to use.

Comment: use the r value produced by the relaimpo package. in the output, you'll find something reading like proportion of variance explained by model: xx.xx%. hope this helps

Comment: run a regression model with the same variables and use the p-value from that